# Calculating pi in pthreads

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I am trying to calculate pi using the bpp method but my result keeps coming up at 0.The whole idea is for each thread to compute a part of it and the sum of each thread gets summed up using the join method

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <time.h>

#define NUM_THREADS     20

void *pi_function(void *p);//returns the value of pi
pthread_mutex_t mutex1 = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER; //creates a mutex variable
double pi=0,p16=1;int k=0;
double sumvalue=0,sum=0;


main()
{
    pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];  //creates the number of threads NUM_THREADS
    int iret1;   //used to ensure that threads are created properly
    //pthread_create(thread,attr,start_routine,arg)

    int i;
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex1, NULL);

    for(i=0;i<NUM_THREADS;i++){
        iret1= pthread_create(&threads[i],NULL,pie_function,(void *) i);
        if(iret1){
            printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", iret1);
            exit(-1);
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<NUM_THREADS;i++){
        iret1=pthread_join(threads[i],&sumvalue);
        if(iret1){
            printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", iret1);
            exit(-1);
        }

        pi=pi+sumvalue;  //my result here keeps returning 0

    }

    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex1);
    printf("Main: program completed. Exiting.\n");
    printf("The value of pi is  : %f\n",pi);

    exit(0);
}

void *pie_function(void * p){
    int rc;
    int k=(int)p;
    sumvalue += 1.0/p16 * (4.0/(8* k + 1) - 2.0/(8*k + 4)
                                          - 1.0/(8*k + 5) - 1.0/(8*k+6));
    pthread_mutex_lock( &mutex1 ); //locks the share variable pi and p16

    p16 *=16;
    rc=pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutex1 );
    if(rc){
        printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
    }
    pthread_exit(&sumvalue); 
}
```

Comment: To start with, please fix your code indentation/whitespace so that it's readable.

Comment: Are you trying to share a single `sumvalue` variable between all of the threads?? I think each one needs its own local sum to then add to the global sum later. But you should at least verify that your implementation works on a single thread if you haven't already.

Comment: @Rup that could be the problem, and qualifies as an answer, imo. The *one thread* advice by itself deserves a +1.

Comment: Your absouletely right.I have it ficed

Comment: Just some nitpicks: your signature of `main` is prehistoric, showing that you probably have not put the appropriate warning level (usually -Wall) on your compilation. There is no need to re-initialize your `mutex1`. **Don't cast an `int` to a `void*`**, they are not of the same width. What you want to do here is to give each thread its own space to hack and in particular to return the result. Don't code threads by using global variables, all your locks and things make not much sense.

Answer (score 0):

For your purpose you don't need to have a mutex or other complicated structure. Just have every thread compute on its own local variables. Provide to each thread the address of a `double` where he receives his `k` and may return the result, in the same way as you already separate the `ptread_t` variables for each thread.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid getting 0 as the output. Put pi=pi+sumvalue inside the join for loop.
since pi=pi+sumvalue is executed only once when sumvalue is very small and pi=0. pi=0 is the output. Just put pi=pi+sumvalue in the join for loop.

To get consistent value of pi follow below mentioned details.

You have to make sure two thinks:-

1. Just make pi as an global variable and remove all global variables. limit the use of many global variable as updating them will become a critical section. Update pi as

pthread mutex lock(&mutex1);

pi += pi + my sum;

pthread mutex unlock(&mutex1);

2. you can also calculate sum_values as:
   void *pie_function(void* rank) {

   long my_rank = (long) rank;

//printf("%ld \n",my_rank);

double factor, sumvalue = 0.0;

long long i;

long long n=1000000;

long long my_n = n/thread_count;

long long my_first_i = my_n*my_rank;

long long my_last_i = my_first_i + my_n;

if (my_first_i % 2 == 0)
factor = 1.0;

else
factor = -1.0;

for (i = my_first_i; i < my_last_i; i++, factor = -factor)
sumvalue+= 4*factor/(2*i+1);

pthread_exit(&sumvalue);
}